# How can I embed a Javascript applet into a metabox in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a wordpress plugin which will require me to write a metabox, and embed a Javascript Express app I wrote for it. The app worked on its own; how can I make it run as an embed in a WP metabox?

Answer (score 0):

create a js file wep_adminext.js, and put it into your theme folder, with code in it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('input[name="wpcf[luogo]"]').geocomplete();
});
```

modify your theme/functions.php, as this:

```
function wep_adminext_js() {
wp_enqueue_script('admin_gmaps_js', '<em><u>hidden link</u></em>', array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('admin_geocomplete_js', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/geocomplete/1.4/jquery.geocomplete.min.js', array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('wep_admin_js', get_template_directory_uri(). '/wep_adminext.js', array('admin_gmaps_js', 'admin_geocomplete_js'));
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wep_adminext_js');
```